# javadoc doclet libs : Illegal package name or ClassCastException when running it

Tags: javadoc, libs, doclet

I am running into the next problem:

I am trying to run my very own and beautiful doclet in the console(Windows 7):

```
javadoc com.mypackages.api -sourcepath ./src/main/java/
```

Which leads me to a mountain of exceptions:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.javadoc.AnnotationTypeDoc
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.AnnotationDescImpl.annotationType(AnnotationDescImpl.java:46)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.isDeprecated(Util.java:811)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.PackageWriterImpl.writeClassesSummary(PackageWriterImpl.java:114)
```

(always the same one).

Then, I found here in StackOverflow someone saying that it was an third-party-library-with-annotations issue ( [StackOverFlow: Why am I getting a ClassCastException when generating javadocs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853/why-am-i-getting-a-classcastexception-when-generating-javadocs) ). The solution looked to be in adding those libraries with annotations to the classpath, so I runned the next line:

```
javadoc com.mindmatics.mcashwebservice.remote.api -sourcepath ./src/main/java/ -docletpath ./all-libs/*.jar
```

And I am now receiving the next error:

```
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "./all-libs/webservice-commons-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

With all the libs included in the all-libs directory. Can anyoune explain me what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much :-)

PS: I am using JDK 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your target path: ./all-libs/*.jar

This is not going to be a proper package name with hyphens in it unfortunately. You'll need to get rid of the hyphen or convert it to an underscore.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that with "docletpath" I could add the jars in a directory (I mean, ./all-libs/ is the directory in which I have all my libs), not a package name.

Answer (score 1):

it seems `*.jar` is expanded by shell into `1.jar 2.jar ...`
listing jar files as `-classpath dir1/1.jar:dir2/2.jar` works for me.